# Arranging numbers c#. if-elseif-else / nested if only(num1 should always be the highest)

Tags: c#

Can someone help me fix this? I tried everthing i know. I made this code but nothing seems to appear when i run it. Thanks

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;
        int Ahighest, b, c, d, Elowest;

        Console.Write("Enter number : ");
        num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter number : ");
        num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter number : ");
        num3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter number : ");
        num4 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter number : ");
        num5 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //highest 
        if (num1 > num2)
        {
            if (num1 > num3)
            {
                if (num1 > num4)
                {
                    if (num1 > num5)
                    {
                        Ahighest = num1;
                        //b 
                        if (num2 > num3)
                        {
                            if (num2 > num4)
                            {
                                if (num2 > num5)
                                {
                                    b = num2;
                                    }
                                    if (num3 > num2)
                                    {
                                        if (num3 > num4)
                                        {
                                            if (num3 > num5)
                                            {
                                                b = num3;
                                                if (num4 > num2)
                                                {
                                                    if (num4 > num3)
                                                    {
                                                        if (num4 > num5)
                                                        {
                                                            b = num4;
                                                            if (num5 > num2)
                                                            {
                                                                if (num5 > num3)
                                                                {
                                                                    if (num5 > num4)
                                                                    {
                                                                        b = num5;
                                                                        //c
                                                                        if (b > num2)
                                                                        {
                                                                            c = num2;
                                                                            if (b > num3)
                                                                            {
                                                                                c = num3;
                                                                                if (b > num4)
                                                                                {
                                                                                    c = num4;
                                                                                    if (b > num5)
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        c = num5;
                                                                                        //d
                                                                                        if (c > num2)
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            d = num2;
                                                                                            if (c > num3)
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                d = num3;
                                                                                                if (c > num4)
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                    d = num4;
                                                                                                    if (c > num5)
                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                        d = num5;
                                                                                                        //lowest
                                                                                                        if (d > num2)
                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                            Elowest = num2;
                                                                                                            if (d > num3)
                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                Elowest = num3;
                                                                                                                if (d > num4)
                                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                    Elowest = num4;
                                                                                                                   if  (d > num5)
                                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                                        Elowest = num5;
                                                                                                                        Console.WriteLine(Ahighest + "," + b + "," + c + "," + d + "," + Elowest);
                                                                                                                        Console.ReadLine();
                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What on earth...

Comment: Holy flipping IF statements.. you've put ALL that crap in and basically under 1 condition you want it to do something, ..and you wonder why it doesnt output something..

Comment: This code is so nested, there's birds living in there.

Comment: Why not put 5 numbers in a list and sort it ? After that take whatever you want.

Comment: I think your code needs to be refactored.

Comment: You have a `if (num3 > num2)` nested a few levels inside of a `if (num2 > num3)`.  Both of those cannot be true.  I stopped looking after I found that, but I'd guess there are other similar cases as well.

Comment: `"I tried everthing i know."` - Then it's time to learn something new.  It's called debugging.  When you execute your application from the IDE in debug mode you can step through the code, line by line, as it executes and observe the runtime values and behaviors.  Give it a try.  Use this to determine specifically where the observed behavior differs from the expected behavior.  Take a look at the variable values when this happens.

Comment: Wow, after coding for sometime, you would remember this day and laugh the hell out

Comment: Still, I'm not really sure why this question is getting down votes...I can't see any legit reason to do that.  The OP's lack of knowledge isn't a reason to down vote.

Comment: @rory.ap I think you can make a case that it shows a lack of research.

Comment: @juharr -- If you were the OP, what would you type in to Google?

Comment: @rory.ap: The lack of debugging is often considered enough reason to down-vote.  It's also often cited as a reason to close, choosing the option where there is not enough information present in the question to describe the problem.  Often also accompanied by a link to Eric Lippert's famous article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @David -- I agree on the close votes, but those are separate from down votes.  Otherwise, they'd be the same thing...

Comment: @rory.ap: Fair enough.  And it's exactly that sort of agreeing and disagreeing which thrives in a voting-based system :)

Comment: @rory.ap "C# how to put numbers in order"?

Comment: @juharr -- how do you ask a targeted question if you don't know what you don't know?

Comment: @rory.ap OK, I don't know what combination of words the OP could randomly type into Google, but why do you care so much?  Hell, I didn't even down vote this, I just gave you a plausible reason others might, but honestly it was likely down-voted as "bad code".  But that's SO for you.

Comment: The best answer you can give now is to use his method correctly before using another method

Answer (score 4):

Instead of comparing every time with the others you could let the framework sort:

```
int[] orderedNumbers = { num1, num2, num3, num4, num5 };
Array.Sort( orderedNumbers );
```

Now you can find the lowest at:

```
orderedNumbers.First();
```

and the highest at:

```
orderedNumbers.Last();
```

or access every number via index (exception if there aren't so many items in the array):

```
int lowest = orderedNumbers[0];
int b = orderedNumbers[1];
int c = orderedNumbers[2];
int d = orderedNumbers[3];
int highest = orderedNumbers[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] nums = new int[5];

for(int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Enter number {i}: ");
    int tempInt;
    bool number = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tempInt);
    nums[i] = number ? tempInt : int.MinValue;
}
Array.Sort(nums);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", nums.Select(x => x == int.MinValue ? "NaN" : x.ToString()).ToArray()));
```

This code will ask the user to input each number, then check that it is actually an integer. If not it will set its value to `-2147483647`, the lowest value possible for an int.

After this it inserts that number into the array at the given index. The array is then sorted, after the string is output in the console, with each number split by a comma.

This code of course runs the risk that if someone, for whatever reason, inputs `-2147483647`, it will say it is not a number. A way around this is to use `int?` like so

```
int?[] nums = new int?[5];

for(int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Enter number {i}: ");
    int tempInt;
    bool number = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tempInt);
    nums[i] = number ? tempInt : null;
}
Array.Sort(nums);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", nums.Select(x => x == null ? "NaN" : x.ToString()).ToArray()));
```

In this code, if the conversion fails - the int is set to null instead of `MinValue`, this is because `int?` is a nullable type. Doing this allows us to have a fallback value without risking someone actually using it as input